# onDisconnectedFromRoom() called when invited player leaves game

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've created a real time multiplayer game with 2 other players (both directly invited). Here is how I did that:

**Created player selection intent**

```
Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(getApiClient(), 1, MAX_PLAYERS);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_GOOGLE_INVITE);
```

**On `onActivityResult()` executed this:**

```
private void onPlayersInvited(Intent data) {
    // get the invitee list
    final ArrayList<String> invitees = data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(1, 5, 0);

    // create the activeRoom and specify a variant if appropriate
    RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
    roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
    roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(getApiClient(), roomConfig);

    // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}


private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder(this).setMessageReceivedListener(this).setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this).setSocketCommunicationEnabled(true)
            .setVariant(subcategory.getId().intValue());
}
```

My game starts on all 3 devices, but when I disconnect from the game on one invited device, then on host device onDisconnectedFromRoom() is called, so I guess the game gets canceled automatically, which is sad, because I'd like to continue the game until min required number of players is present.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird behaviour was caused by seting AutomatchCryteria. I removed it and now it behaves well

Answer (score 2):

In onDisconnectedFromRoom() callback you get Room object. You may check how many players stay in room by calling

```
int count = room.getParticipantIds().size();
```

If players more than minimal then continue game.

Comment: But will, this user keep geting messages from other players even if the onDisconnectedFromRoom() was called?

Comment: You can test it easy. Just try to send data after onDisconnectedFromRoom() was called.

Comment: Have you implement other method from RoomStatusUpdateListener?

Comment: Sure I did implement them.

Comment: It won't work as also onPeersDisconnected() is called, and from now on host participant has disconnected status in the room...

Comment: Besides room.getParticipantIds() will return collection of all participants, also disconnected ones. I have to check connected status